# Include header fields in a HTTP request that should result in a Domain change

Tags: javascript, html, rest, http, api-design

I have an API that authenticates the request based on the header fields and then returns a HTML page.

The request to this API has to be made in a way, such that **the domain will change from `domain1.com` to `domain2.com`** (Just like clicking a hypertext).

I cannot use `<a>Link</a>` because I need to add header fields.
And `ajax` cannot be used because it does not change controls from `domain1.com` to `domain2.com`.

Something like this did not make sense at all...

```
$.ajax({
 // Use ajax to authenticate
 ...
 success : function(path){

     // Load the path for domain change
     location.assign(path);      
     // Even this request should have a header field
 },
 ...    
})
```

I need the functionalities of both(changing domains and header usage) in a single request - if possible or at the least with 2 requests.

Any ideas to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by, "the domain will change"?  That statement doesn't make any sense.  Change it where?  Are you just looking for a redirect?  And what would this ever have to do with AJAX?

Comment: Are you looking for `302 redirect`?

Comment: @Brad When we click  `<a>somewebsite.com</a>`, the `URL` will change to  somewebsite.com - This is what I meant by domain change. I need ajax to set header fields.

Comment: @shaochuancs 302 will not help... as it serves the request from a different URL but does not change the URL of the browser window( to be clear) to the redirection. Am I correct?

Comment: The URL will change... you mean the URL in the address bar?  No, a 302 will change that URL.  You should actually try it.

Comment: @Brad I made an experiment and find that `302 redirect` response of Ajax request is retrieved by Ajax handler, it won't trigger browser behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

In order to send HTTP request with credential in header, and "change domain" when it is successful, you can use JSON response with `302` code and `Location` -- just a convention, browser behaviour won't be triggered.

An example response:

```
HTTP response code: 200 OK

HTTP response body:
{
  status: 302,
  location: 'domain2.com/result'
}
```

The Ajax code would look like:

```
$.ajax({
  // Use ajax to authenticate, with credential in HTTP header
  ...
  success: function(result){
    if (result.status === 302) {
      window.location = result.location;
    }
  },
  ...    
})
```

2 HTTP requests will be used. One for Ajax, and another for the redirection.

Comment: Redirection here doesn't change the window URL. It's only serving my request at the redirected URL.  So, from the redirected URL I can fetch the HTML and insert it into my page. But, then I want to move to the redirected page. How do I do it? I cant do using normal location.assign() without a header.

Comment: @samkirubaharan Sorry that I made a mistake. I'm confused with another scenario. The answer has been updated. Please check.

Comment: Where you able to handle it this way?. For me, the browser redirects automatically. And I can only handle the response for that redirected call and not this initial call.

Comment: @samkirubaharan Please note the HTTP response code is `200`, not `302`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Now, the problem is  the new `window.location` will not have the header fields. And my request needs header fields. I mentioned exactly that in my code.

Comment: @samkirubaharan Why do you need to add custom header in page visiting? Is this header about authentication such as `Authorization` in basic auth?

Comment: @samkirubaharan To implement page protection, you can use Cookie.

Comment: Not exactly. But for Authentication. Didn't think about cookie based authentication. But, that can't be the answer  I'm trying to find.

Comment: @samkirubaharan There are only 2 ways to do authentication (would be glad if the 3rd way exists): Authentication based on Header, and Authentication based on Cookie. Authentication based on Header (such as Basic/Digest auth) is old and insecure. You should use Cookie based solution. Why you think Cookie-based-solution is not the answer you are trying to find?

Comment: Apart from authentication, I'm trying to make such synchronous-like header-included HTTP requests. That's why. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @samkirubaharan OK. If you want browser to take some custom data when sending request, you need Cookie.